# playing audio samples in html5

Tags: javascript, html, audio, websocket

my web application is working using websockets. It's receiving audio samples from server in 100ms interval (each sample is 100ms long). How can I play this samples in browser? I've tried with AduioBuffer and AudioBufferSourceNode, but without luck.
Thanks!

```
audioContext = new AudioContext();
playingBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, 4096, 44100);
sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
sourceNode.buffer = playingBuffer;
observer.setVoicePacketCallback(function (data) {
    // data has Float32Array type
    playingBuffer.copyToChannel(data, 1);
    sourceNode.play();
});
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show us some code with WebAudio?